# Javascript two array merge( key and value)

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, key

I have two array. I want to merge this two arrays into one array. One array consisting keys and another one values.My array looks like

```
productId = [8,7,9];//Key Element
quantity = ["5","1","3"];//Value Element
//expected new array
newarray = {
    "8": 5,
    "7": 1,
    "9": 3
}
```

I already tried to merge these arrays, in this way

```
var newArray = {};
for(var i=0; i< productId.length; i++){
  newArray[productId[i]] = quantity [i];
}
console.log(newArray);
```

It returns

```
Object [ <7 empty slots>, "5", "1", "3" ]
```

Comment: Your code works fine, please share a working fiddle or snippet to demonstrate/replicate your issue.

Comment: You seems like creating array of objects instead of Array

Comment: @AuxTaco Which browser?

Comment: Mozila Firefox and Google chrome booth

Comment: You will get your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513811/empty-slots-in-javascript-objects

Comment: @AuxTaco Yup was about to delete my comments. Sourabh just linked a questions that highlights the bug of FF.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513811/empty-slots-in-javascript-objects

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
var productId = [8,7,9];//Key Element
var quantity = ["5","1","3"];//Value Element

var obj = {};
var i = 0;
for(var k of productId) {
    obj[k] = parseInt(quantity[i]);
    i++;
}
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Also, this is a very bad implementation of `.map`. You are updating an object and returning in map. and the you use `[0]`  for display purpose. This is just wrong

Comment: still it returns [<7 empty slots>, "5", "1"."3" ]

Comment: @Rajesh no it was not intended for you

Answer (score 0):

You are working in firefox so you may get this type of issue because the problem might be caused at how Firefox' console.log has interpreted the input object.

Please look here

[Empty slots in JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513811/empty-slots-in-javascript-objects)

Try this

```js
var productId = [8,7,9];
var quantity = ["5","1","3"];
var newarray = {};
productId.forEach((key, i) => newarray[key] = quantity[i]);
console.log(newarray);
```

Comment: Please specify what's wrong with OP's code as well. Why your code works and OP's doesn't?

Comment: @Rajesh Hey this is the problem in Firefox

Comment: I have Updated my answer where you will find link look into that

Comment: Thanks! Being a chrome user, I was not aware about it.

Comment: @Rajesh Welcome bro :)

Answer (score 0):

Your new "array" is not an `Array` but an `Object`.

You can iterate on one of the arrays using `Array.reduce` to construct the object.

Something like that:

```js
const arr1 = ['8', '2', '4'];
const arr2 = ['28', '12', '45'];

const result = arr1.reduce((obj, currentItem, index) => {
  obj[currentItem] = arr2[index];
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```