# How do arrays store empty values - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Not too long ago, I discovered that arrays in JavaScript need not contain an ordered set of keys (`0-x`) to store values within it

and some numeric keys may not be defined (`0-4 ... 6-x`, where `5` is not defined).

---

And this creates semantically two types of arrays that are similar:

`arrayA = [, ,]` (*partially-empty arrays* or *sparse arrays*)

`arrayB = [undefined, undefined]` (*filled arrays*)

---

But recently, I was tinkering with JavaScript in the ***Google Chrome Developer Console*** and came across this:

[image]

Now the second array is like `arrayA`, and the third like `arrayB` as shown in the console.

But the first array (`[...'‍♀️']`)... what is it?

I opened up its *directory* and saw the elements that were defined as *`hole`* were `undefined` with their respective keys in the array.

[image]

I also ran a few types of JavaScript loops on the array:

- `for...in` statement captures all elements, except the *`hole`*s.
- `for...of` statement captures all elements, except the *`hole`*s and proceeds to throw an error that the iterator variable used is `undefined` i.e.:

  `for (var value of [...'‍♀️']) console.log(value);`

  `// Throw 'ReferenceError' when loop is done.`
- `Array.prototype.forEach` method captures all elements, except the *`hole`*s.
- `do...while`, `for` and `while` statements captures all elements, except the *`hole`*s.

Why does the console see those values as different from *`empty`* or *`undefined`* (as with `arrayA` and `arrayB`)?

---

The main question is: Is there implicitly another type of array and if so, is there anything to note about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty slots in JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513811/empty-slots-in-javascript-objects)

Comment: See: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-array-exotic-objects

Comment: The example with emoji cluster (footballer) seems weird. Can you post this cluster somehow as a code line, not as an image?

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt. Here ya go: [...'‍♀️']

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner

Comment: @Lapys `...` splits by codepoints. And that single emoji is comprised of multilple codepoints, see the link I posted above

Comment: I cannot understand the holes/`undefined`'s at the end of the spread string. What do they represent in the cluster? I have only 5 codepoints from the code above in the comment, without holes/`undefined`'s in my Chrome Canary console.

Comment: @Lapys This info can be useful: [Holes in Arrays](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch18.html#array_holes) from the "Speaking JavaScript" by Dr. Axel Rauschmayer; [ES6 and holes in Arrays](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrays.html#sec_array-holes) from the "Exploring ES6" by Dr. Axel Rauschmayer; [Elements kinds in V8](https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds) by Mathias Bynens (with implementation details and performance tips).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `...` is known as spread syntax. Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Emojis are made up of a variety of elements which the browser renders as a single emoji. Here's a quick article that expands on that. https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/2f488279a3-expand-emojis-with-the-spread-operator

By applying the spread syntax to an emoji, you can look at the individual emojis it's composed of.

Comment: `...` is not an _operator_, even the link you referred to does not call it an "operator".

Comment: @zerkms funnily enough, it's in the directory `/Operators/`.

Comment: Never mind, I just found out what's happening at MDN: they put bot *expressions* and *operators* under the directory `/Operators/`.