# Possible to push empty slot to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm building my own map method to be as close as the native map method.
Since the native map pushes(i think) the changed values into a new array, it still keeps the empty slots. I wasn't able to find a solution to push an empty slot into an array, like this example below.

```
[1, 2, 3].push(some code) // [1, 2, 3, empty]
```

I tried pushing an array with one empty item prefixed with a spread operator `arr.push(...(new Array(1)))` or `arr.push(...[,])` but that just pushes `undefined`.

I solved my [problem](https://gist.github.com/aquaductape/aa992b96ed2fb0fccef5af1f40a4e63d) by not using push and instead assigning values to the array index that way skipped indices will be set to empty.

But I'm writing this post to see if anyone knows that if it's possible to use the push method to push an empty slot to an array.

Comment: It's not possible to push an empty slot. `.push` adds an item to the array, while an empty slot is the notion of *no* item in the array. There is no "nothing" available anywhere in JS - `null` and `undefined` are actual things that exist but *represent* a nothing, aren't actually a nothing.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44516328/574531) for a detailed look at what is actually going on when there are empty slots in an array -- specifically, there are no keys for the "empty" slots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible, not with the `push` method. `empty` can only exist if the array has a certain length, but a whole number property of the array does not exist at some index. This is called a **sparse array**, and cannot be created with `push` (or other array methods, if they're called on and with non-sparse arrays).

The only way to do so would be to assign to an index for which a *lower* index doesn't exist yet.

Look at the results for the below two snippets in your browser console, not the snippet console:

```js
const arr = [];
arr[1] = 'a';
console.log(arr);
```

Or to set the `.length` of the array above the last index that the array has:

```js
const arr = [];
arr.length = 1;
console.log(arr);
```

But the two approaches above are *very weird* to do and probably have no good reason to be used. Better to avoid sparse arrays entirely.

Keep in mind that an empty slot is different from `undefined`, which is perfectly possible to have as an array value:

```js
const arr = [];
arr.push(undefined);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I guess your intention is for people to check the browser console when running the snippets. I was running them and wondering why no output was there.

Comment: I edited the post by adding console need to be reviewed

Comment: @saketh The snippet console never displays the `empty` that OP is looking for, not even for sparse arrays - have to look at the results for the first two snippets in the browser console instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty slot in an array by incrementing the array length:

```js
var a = []
a.push(1)
a.length++
a.push(3)
console.log(a)
console.log(1 in a) // anything at index 1?
```

Alternatively, you can push something and then delete it:

```js
var a = []
a.push(1)
a.push(2)
a.push(3)
delete a[1]
console.log(a)
console.log(1 in a) // anything at index 1?
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to actually push to a new array in your implementation. You can simply do `new Array(this.length)` where `this.length` is the array you are mapping through length.

For example consider this `map` implementation:

```js
if (!Array.prototype.mapIt) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "mapIt", {
    value: function(fn) {
      if (this === null) {
        throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.mapIt called on null or undefined');
      }
      if (typeof fn !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
      }
      let _array = this.filter(x => x != null) // remove empty values
      let result = new Array(_array.length) // the new array we will return
      for (var i = 0; i < _array.length; i++) {
        result[i] = fn.call(arguments[1], _array[i], i, _array) // call the predicate
      }
      return result;
    }
  });
}

let arr = [1, 2, , , 3] // the test array

let result = arr.mapIt((c, i, a) =>
  console.log(`current: ${c}`, `index: ${i}`, `array: ${a}`) || c + 2)

console.log('result: ', result)
console.log('original array: ', arr)
```

Hope this helps you with an gives you an idea about a possible `map` implementation.

Comment: thanks for sharing your implementation, but you forgot to add a condition that contains the `fn.call` if the key exists inside the array `if(i in this)`, otherwise when you map over an array with `[1,2 , , , 3]`, it will return those empty items as `undefined` when it should remain empty because they are skipped.

Comment: Good point @CalebTaylor. Completely forgot about this. I added it via `Array.filter` before the for loop. In any case this is not perfect by any means but it was more of an example of an implementation without the `push` since you did not provide yours etc.